# Axios API call to WordPress on the same server

Tags: wordpress, axios, cors, nuxt.js, apache2

I have WordPress installed on the same machine of NuxtJs, and I'm using Axios to get WordPress posts, but I keep getting a CORS policy error.
If I try to call API of another WordPress site it gets the posts and all is fine.

On my development server I set 2 different Apache virtual hosts:

- wp.test.local -> WordPress
- test.local -> NuxtJs

In order to have only 1 domain and 1 subdomain in production too.

How can I get this running? Any ideas?

Comment: CORS should be fixed on the backend aka Wordpress. Did you tried googling `CORS wordpress`? There is probably either a plugin or a setting to configure.

Comment: @kissu yes I tried, but I didn't understand that the origin had to be set on the API target (WordPress) so I was trying to set headers on Axios call. See my answer for details.

Comment: CORS is always to be set on the backend because it's a security saying who can make actions on the backend. Otherwise, if it was be done on Axios, everybody could access your API and do what pleases them.